# Use RxBinding to make observable to be emitted when user click send button in chat layout

Tags: android

I want to Use Rxbinding to make a chat layout in Android by using RxTextView.textChanges(textView) and RxView.clicks(button). But the way I want it is as below:

I am going to use RxTextView.textChanges(textView) to listen of textchanges so when user type at least one character it will enable send button.  And make RxTextView emitting the string that user typed in the TextView as an observable when RXView.clicks() happened, means when user click the button.  So pretty much I want to combine these two operator RxTextView and RXView.clicks to accomplish to get observable when user click the button

Thank you all any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to validate something. You can check [this](https://github.com/ashraf-patel/RxFormValidation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ashraf/rxformvalidation/LoginActivity.java) example in which Form-validation is being shown.

```
RxTextView
.textChanges(textview)
.map(charSequence ->charSequence.toString())
.subscribe(string -> {
    if(string.length() > 0) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }        
    else {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
})
```